# How to create a "loop" statement within an {expect} script?

Tags: tcl, expect

Assumption is, this is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set a "__test__"
```

i would like to create a loop inside this script so it can print the value for

```
 $a
```

with the a number infront of it based on the loop.

so if i wanted it to loop 3 times.. end product would become:

```
 1:__test__
 2:__test__
 3:__test__
```

Comment: How is this relevant to python tag?

Comment: @alecxe, well python seems to be a native linux program that works inside the terminal, so i thought it was related

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [for](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/for.htm)

```expect
#!/usr/bin/expect
set a "__test__"
for {set x 0} {$x<3} {incr x} {
   puts "$x:$a"
}
```

See more info in [tcl commands](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/contents.htm) because `expect` is an extension to `tcl` language.