# How to loop until I don't get any of the listed options as prompt

Tags: tcl, expect

How can I loop on below until I don't have those options as "yes", "assword" or "vt100"?

```
expect {
       "yes" {send "yes\r"}
       "assword:" {send "123456\r"}
       "vt100" {send "\r"}
       }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a "loop" statement within an {expect} script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412485/how-to-create-a-loop-statement-within-an-expect-script)

Comment: sounds like you can use `exp_continue`. see Expect's [manual](https://man.cx/expect) for details.

Comment: By default, that `expect` will wait until one of those is presented, or it times out, or an EOF is reached.